# Unable to run unit tests on Gtk Application more than once in same test program

Tags: unit-testing, gtk, dbus, vala

I am writing a series of unit tests on a Gtk Application in Vala and I have encountered a problem with instantiating and running a Gtk Application more than once inside the test program.

The first time the application is instantiated and run everything works as expected but the subsequent times it fails with the message:

```
Failed to register: An object is already exported for the interface org.gtk.Application at /org/valarade/testtools
```

From what I understand of the Gtk Application life cycle the Application has registered itself on the local DBus session bus as a single instance application which prevents additional instances from being run.

Using the d-feet application I am able to watch the application register itself on the local bus the first time it runs and it appears to deregister itself when the running test function terminates. There is no trace of it when the subsequent test function instantiates and runs a new instance but the above error is returned nonetheless.

I have tried several things, including making sure that all the objects referenced by the application are destroyed as well as the application object itself between test functions. I have tried calling connection.close_sync in the class destructor and setting register_session to false but neither had any effect.

The sample code for the Test Program

```
static void main (string[] args) {

    Gtk.test_init (ref args);

    TestSuite.get_root ().add_suite (new FileLoaderPluginTests ().get_suite ());

    Idle.add (() => {
        Test.run ();
        Gtk.main_quit ();
        return true;
    });

    Gtk.main ();
}
```

and the code for the Test Suite

```
public FileLoaderPluginTests () {
    add_test ("method on_open_activate ()", file_loader_on_open_activate);
    add_test ("method on_open_response_ok ()", file_loader_on_open_response_ok);
}


public void file_loader_on_open_activate () {
    var app = new MockApplication ();

    app.activate.connect ((a) => {
        var action = app.shell.lookup_action ("file_open");
        action.activate (null);
        app.quit();
    });

    app.run ();
    app = null;

}

public void file_loader_on_open_response_ok () {
    var app = new MockApplication ();

    app.activate.connect ((a) => {
        var action = app.shell.lookup_action ("file_open");
        action.activate (null);
        app.quit();
    });

    app.run ();
}
```

It appears to me that the DBus session registration is for the life of the running Test program not the Application class itself. I've been through the precious little documentation there is and I can't seem to grock anything that would allow me deregister the Application after each test.

Although I can work around this by setting up distinct Test programs for each unit test, this seems to be a lot of unnecessary duplication. Ideally I would like to have one test program for each logical unit in the whole application whereas this way it could result in quite a number by the time there's any significant code coverage.

My question is then - is there any way I can create, run and destroy a Gtk Application multiple times within a Test program? Alternatively, is there a better way to test Gtk Applications that obviates this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DBus communication is asynchronous, I would guess that your application name hasn't deregistered from the bus yet by the time the next test starts up the next application.

Some tips for testing Application classes:

- You can append a unique identifier (e.g. the PID plus the system clock time) to the application ID when you create each application; that way, the applications will never clash with each other. This is especially advisable if you might be running test programs in parallel (which Automake does by default these days.)
- If possible, keep your logic out of your application class and in smaller units so that you don't have to create an application instance for every test. Starting up and shutting down an application instance in each test makes them very slow.

PS. I believe `Test.run()` already runs a main loop for you, so you don't need to start the test suite in an idle function.

Comment: I suspected as much with DBus and was writing some asynchronous test code but - ugh - and your solution is less convoluted.

I had considered adding a unique identifier to the Application ID but thought it might mess with the automatic loading of resources, but apparently not. 

I have broken the app down into the smallest units I can but I still need to test some UI functionality and for this I created Mock versions of the Application and ApplicationWindow so they run quite fast. 

Thanks a lot, I appreciate the concise, thoughtful and accurate response!